# pexpect: expect various lines

Tags: python, edit, pexpect

I am trying to use pexpect to scp files from a server, but it seems to do nothing (not even an error message). Here is my code:

```
import pexpect
child=pexpect.spawn('scp -r user@host:route/file .')
child.expect("user@host's password:")
child.sendline('password')
```

I think that problem is in the child.expect command, because  "user@host's password:" is the last line of a some 30 lines welcome message which include special caracters. Is there any way to tell pexpect to expect more than one line or simply anything? Or just to wait X secs and then input the password?

EDIT: It works with the child.wait() command, but it stops at the 9th file. It happens that the 10th is very big (about 250Mb), I don't know if it has something to do with it... Thank you!!

EDIT: I put the line

```
child.logfile=sys.stdout
```

after

```
child=pexpect.spawn('scp -r user@host:route/file .')
```

and what I get in the screen, NOT in a file, is the welcome message which finishes by "user@host's password:", then I saw the password in the same line, but I still don't get the files.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: 'expect' will keep scanning until it sees the string you gave it, so the code you've given should work. Try setting `child.logfile = sys.stdout` in order to see what's happening.

Comment: try to add `child.wait()` at the end, to wait for the child to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at pexpect's attribute buffer's:
- pexpect.before # string parsed BEFORE matching the regex specified in pexpect.expect
- pexpect.buffer # string presently in buffer
- pexpect.after  # string parsed AFTER matching the regex specified in pexpect.expect

Remember that child.expect() is a blocking call and will not return until either it matches the regex or it hits EOF/TIMEOUT exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to [pexpect documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#special-eof-and-timeout-patterns)

> The pattern given to expect() may be a regular expression or it may also be a list of regular expressions. This allows you to match multiple optional responses. The expect() method returns the index of the pattern that was matched. For example, say you wanted to login to a server. After entering a password you could get various responses from the server – your password could be rejected; or you could be allowed in and asked for your terminal type; or you could be let right in and given a command prompt.

and the example from the documentation:

```py
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(my_secret_password)
# We expect any of these three patterns...
i = child.expect (['Permission denied', 'Terminal type', '[#\$] '])
if i==0:
    print('Permission denied on host. Can\'t login')
    child.kill(0)
elif i==1:
    print('Login OK... need to send terminal type.')
    child.sendline('vt100')
    child.expect('[#\$] ')
elif i==2:
    print('Login OK.')
    print('Shell command prompt', child.after)
```